# Creating folders inside directory in R and save results there with the name of file names to save plots

Tags: r, loops

I have data for 150 managers. I have created six graphs for each managers. I need to create a folder for each manager which contains all those graphs (so in total, 150 folders, within which are six graphs). Is there a generic loop that I could use to do this?

So far, all i have managed is this:

```
setwd("C:/Users/zeina/Desktop/Gunter")
subfolder_names <- c(1:150) 
for (i in 1:length(subfolder_names)){
    folder<-dir.create(paste0("Manager - ", subfolder_names[i]))
}
```

This produces the folders for me (ex. Manager - 1, Manager - 2, etc.). But i do not know how then to have R save the graphs for me within each of these folders for each manager

Comment: Do you have the plots are objects in the R workspace (and how are they named?) or have you already saved them all in the same place on disk?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add additional statements inside the loop. For each loop, you need to set wd to the folder that you've just created, then save the plots there. You may want to add additional loop for plot files as well.

```
setwd("C:/Users/zeina/Desktop/Gunter")
subfolder_names <- c(1:150) 
for (i in 1:length(subfolder_names)){
    setwd("C:/Users/zeina/Desktop/Gunter")
    folder<-dir.create(paste0("Manager - ", subfolder_names[i]))
    setwd(paste0("C:/Users/zeina/Desktop/Gunter/", "Manager - ", subfolder_names[i]))
    for (i in 1:length(subfolder_names)){
        jpeg(file=paste0("plot", i, ".jpeg")
        # Here you need to type the code for plot #
        dev.off()
    }
}
```

If you want to save the plots with extensions other than jpeg, just change `jpeg()` to that extension, i.e. `png()`.

Comment: So I tried the code above, and it created one folder, and pasted all 150 graphs there. What I'll need is different: I need to create 150 folders for each of the 150 managers. I then create a graph in a loop so that it produces 150 graph for each manager. Each graph for each individual manager then needs to go to the assigned manager - I hope I'm making sense? So for instance, in the Manager -1 folder, there needs to be a graph for that manager, in the Manager -2 folder, a graph for that manager, etc.

Comment: As I said, you may need to add additional loop for plots. Can you provide details about how you draw plots for each folder?

Comment: I've updated the solution. Now there will be 150 folders, and inside each folder there will be 150 graph.